# Retries slow process in pyspark EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm running a Spark cluster in EMR. All of the execution works fine but, in a specific stage, it returns to process previows stages showing retry in the console:

[image: Spark EMR stages]

In the console aren't any errors but it retries the stages. I'm using EMR version 6.2.0 which uses Spark 3.0.1 version.

Why is Spark making this retries?

Comment: Have you checked the yarn logs?

Comment: Yes, I don't see anything